# using index like blacklist when searching on other index on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a user system using Elasticsearch.
I want to fetch data for all users from an index called 'Users' and exclude users whose names are listed in an index called 'BannedUsers'.

In a SQL query, it would look like this: `SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [name] NOT IN (SELECT [name] FROM [BannedUsers])`.

Is there any way to use a specific index as a blacklist when searching against another index?

I'd like to do everything with a single QueryDSL request.

indecs mapping.

```
POST Users
{
 "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
         "type":"text"
    }
  }
}

POST BannedUsers
{
 "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
         "type":"text"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the enrichment policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html) and filter the data. Basically, each document in Users index will have a field after the enrichment like `is_banned: true` and the query will look like the following:

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "is_banned": false
    }
  }
}
```